# how to strip invisible char from utf-8 chars

Tags: java, utf-8

I wrote a program to generate a random utf-8 string, but there are some messy chars.
I don't know if my code is wrong or some chars are invisible, how can it strip these messy chars(but I want to keep the chinese, korean, japanese, symbols and so on)?

There is the code:

```
private byte randomByteInRange(int min, int max) {
    return (byte) (min + rand.nextInt(max - min));
}

private String randomUtf8String(int length) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    int j = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[6 * length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        int mod = i % 3;
        if (0 == mod) { // 0xxxxxxx, visible char: 0x20 ~ 0x80
            bytes[j++] = randomByteInRange(0x20, 0x80);
        }
        if (1 == mod) { // 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
            bytes[j++] = randomByteInRange(0xc0, 0xdf);
            bytes[j++] = randomByteInRange(0x80, 0xbf);
        }
        if (2 == mod) { // 1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
            bytes[j++] = randomByteInRange(0xe0, 0xef);
            bytes[j++] = randomByteInRange(0x80, 0xbf);
            bytes[j++] = randomByteInRange(0x80, 0xbf);
        }
    }

    return new String(bytes, 0, j, "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\p{C}+", "");
}
```

there is my output:

```
kѷ㱾U׽拌w��Ꙙ@
```

Comment: UTF-8 is kinda hard because each character maps to a variable number of bytes. Why not use UTF-16 instead, where each normal character is exactly two bytes, then convert back to UTF-8?

Comment: this code is for testing a web service interface, the client will input utf8 encoded strings

Comment: Well... you're returning a `String` from that method, not bytes, so it's irrelevant what bytes you use to construct it.

Comment: I see. but how to enumerate the visible char in UTF-16?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of several problems with generating random strings in this manner:

- unassigned ranges, reserved ranges and the private use area
- control characters
- combining marks (e.g. [diacritics](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0300.pdf)) that are only meaningful following certain other code points
- font support (e.g. will your device display [Ogham script](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1680.pdf)?)

In order to implement a meaningful random string generator, your code will need to apply some filters and natural language heuristics.

*See [the charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) for reference.*

---

Assuming this is for localization smoke testing...

As an alternative approach, consider using common phrases, dates, etc. from the target language or using some sort of Markov chain generated from a target language text source. Automated translation software could also give you a reasonable representation of the target string.

Comment: Actually, this code is for testing. Simulating input of user, the user can input any character as the prompt of password. " your code will need to apply some filters and natural language heuristics." can you give me some tips?

Comment: @jamee - I'd start by reading the [Unicode specification](http://unicode.org/standard/standard.html). Your target Java version documentation will tell you which version of the spec it implements. I would also read up on [character properties](http://unicode.org/reports/tr44/).

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, write :

```
Character c;
c.i
```

and put the moose cursor just after the `c.i` 
then enter `CTRL+SPACE` and search words beginning by `is`.

Test your inputs with all the `is` you want.